# Arcmap ModelBuilder - If statement

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, con

I'm using the ModelBuilder inside ArcMap to execute a set of raster calculations. I need to execute a different calculations based on the pixel value (If the pixel value is less then 0 - execute calculation no.2, If above 0 - execute calculation no.3).
Of course in the same raster can be both cases, so I need it to indeed chech every pixel and execute the appropiate following calculation per pixel.

Any idea how to do such thing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the conditional tool:
`Con((raster<x),(eq1),Con((raster>x), (eq2),(eq3 or constant)))`
where eq1 your first calculation for true statement, eq2 your calculation for your second true statement and eq3 or a constant for your false statement.

For example, for dataset Raster1 that has value ranging between 1:10, if Raster1 <=5 but >0 you need to multiply the values, if Raster1 is >5 you want to add the values and if it is 0 you want to set it to -1.

`Con(((Raster1 >0) &(Raster1 <= 5)),(Raster1 x Raster1), Con((Raster1 >5), (Raster1 +Raster1),-1))`